# Keeping all history when moving from svn to git

Tags: git, git-svn

Can all history be kept when moving from svn to git?
I find that history prior to an **svn copy** is lost.

I have the following svn repository:

- project1/trunk/A
- project2/trunk/dir/B
- project3/trunk

  - A  *- copied from project1*
  - dir/B  *- copied from project2*

If I git svn clone project3, there is no history for A and B from project1 and project2.

Here's a demonstration of the problem:

```
> svn co https://localhost/svn/test
> cd test
> mkdir -p project1/trunk project1/branches project1/tags
> mkdir -p project2/trunk/dir project2/branches project2/tags
> mkdir -p project3/trunk project3/branches project3/tags
> touch project1/trunk/A project2/trunk/dir/B
> svn add project1 project2 project3
> svn ci -m 'initial commit'
> svn copy project1/trunk/A project3/trunk/
> svn copy project2/trunk/dir project3/trunk/
> svn ci -m 'project restructure'
```

Running **svn log** for each shows both revisions:

```
> svn log project3/trunk/A 
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 r2 | tanderson | 2015-04-16 19:37:33 +1000 (Thu, 16 Apr 2015) | 1 line

 project restructure
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 r1 | tanderson | 2015-04-16 19:37:32 +1000 (Thu, 16 Apr 2015) | 1 line

 initial commit
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> svn log project3/trunk/dir/B 
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 r2 | tanderson | 2015-04-16 19:37:33 +1000 (Thu, 16 Apr 2015) | 1 line

 project restructure
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 r1 | tanderson | 2015-04-16 19:37:32 +1000 (Thu, 16 Apr 2015) | 1 line

 initial commit
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now for the clone:

```
> git svn clone --stdlayout --follow-parent https://localhost/svn/test/project3 gittest
  Using higher level of URL: https://localhost/svn/test/project3 => https://localhost/svn/test
  r1 = 1bc0768d6d823b49305978d227df6834d2787fdc (refs/remotes/origin/trunk)
       A       A
       A       dir/B
  r2 = c71c15ec116a7ada952d8457d50902c970616ef5 (refs/remotes/origin/trunk)
  Checked out HEAD:
      https://localhost/svn/test/project3/trunk r2
```

I'm hoping to see both revisions of A and B, but in both cases only the final revision is shown. E.g.

```
> cd gittest
> git log --follow A
   commit c71c15ec116a7ada952d8457d50902c970616ef5
   Author: tanderson <tanderson@897fde24-c897-6841-ad7f-93f2e7295302>
   Date:   Thu Apr 16 09:37:33 2015 +0000

    project restructure

    git-svn-id: https://localhost/svn/test/project3/trunk@2 897fde24-c897-6841-ad7f-93f2e7295302
```

I've tried the following tools:

- https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git
- https://github.com/fragglet/agito
- http://www.subgit.com/
- http://www.catb.org/esr/reposurgeon/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the simple test repository above, [svn-all-fast-export](https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git) works.

It's written in C++ and doesn't have binaries. I was able to build it using cygwin.

To covert the sample svn repository above:

1. copy the svn repository locally (using svnadmin hotcopy or svnsync)
2. create an authors file, users.txt, as per https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git
3. create a rules file, rules.txt to instruct svn-fast-all-export how to process repository paths:

   ```
   create repository testnew
   end repository

   match /project1/trunk/
       repository testnew
       branch project1
   end match

   match /project2/trunk/
       repository testnew
       branch project2
   end match

   match /project3/trunk/
       repository testnew
       branch master
   end match
   ```
4. Run:

   ```
   svn-all-fast-export --identity-map=users.txt --rules=rules.txt --stats /path/to/repo/test.svn
   ```

This will create a git repository, **testnew** in the current directory.
The **git log** command shows both revisions for A and B. E.g.:

```
> git log A
  commit eb561b48109620fc64f9f7cf15a752b1730f8d18
  Merge: e3a02bf e1cc2a9
  Author: tanderson <tanderson@localhost>
  Date:   Sun May 24 06:00:36 2015 +0000

     project restructure

  commit e3a02bff6a7ace21b3789c4f9350e969add44541
  Author: tanderson <tanderson@localhost>
  Date:   Sun May 24 06:00:35 2015 +0000

     initial commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. There are tools for this purpose.

One common tools is https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git. It translates the complete svn history to git.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same issue with svn2git i.e. the git log command only lists the history after the svn copy.